# How to get a malloc() allocation in a function to get a different and new block of memory every time the function is called?

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that reads some data from a `FILE*` and saves it to a `struct`. The data being read works just fine, but the struct that it returns does not change it's address everytime the function is called, whereas my intuition tells me this should not be the case.

Here is the typedef of the struct

```
#define BYTE uint8_t

typedef struct node {
    uint32_t length;
    uint32_t type;
    uint32_t crc;
    BYTE* data;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

And here is the misbehaving function

```
node readChunk() {  // Returns a node with the data of the next chunk in infile.

    node newNode = *((node*)(malloc(sizeof(node))));
  
    // Bunch of file IO; Read data into newNode

    return newNode;
}
```

When I run *this* snippet

```
node tmp;

for(unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    tmp = readChunk();
    printf("%p\n", &tmp);
}
```

Here is the output I get

```
0x7ffd684d2030
0x7ffd684d2030
0x7ffd684d2030
0x7ffd684d2030
0x7ffd684d2030
0x7ffd684d2030
0x7ffd684d2030
0x7ffd684d2030
0x7ffd684d2030
```

The reason I used `*((node*)(malloc(sizeof(node))))` is because it would allocate memory in the heap so that the values remain even after the function call is over, but could that also be causing this problem?

I'm still learning low-level concepts like memory-management and stack/heap but my guess is that the compiler allocates a fixed `sizeof(node)` bytes block of memory for `node newNode` at runtime and this block of memory (which happens to be at `0x7ffd684d2030`, for the test run I did) gets used every time the function is called.

This explanation makes sense to me, but if I happen to be wrong, what else could be causing this issue, and if I happen to be right, how do I go about resolving this? That is, how do I write a function (or any reusable block of code) that can create a new block of memory **everytime** it is called?

Comment: `*((node*)(malloc(sizeof(node))))` - the number of weird casts and derefs should tell you. `newNode ` is of type `node`. `malloc` returns a pointer. No number of casts will magically turn a pointer into a `struct`

Comment: If you're returning by value, `malloc()` is neither appropriate nor useful.

Comment: These all have the same address because they're all the same `tmp` variable on the stack. You just keep stomping over it again and again with other values.

Comment: Tip: `return` a `node*`. Use a pointer in your main function. Chain these together properly.